# Reflection MemberInfo to Func<T1, T2>

Tags: c#, reflection, func

I'm looking for a method to convert instance of `MemberInfo` to "Func" type (to use it through lambda expression later).

Lets, say I have a member function of type

```
public bool func(int);
```

Using reflection, I somehow get instance of `MemberInfo` "mi", now i want to convert it to `Func<int, bool>;` type. something like:

```
Func<int, bool f = myType.GetMember(mi.Name);
```

Is there a way to do it?

ps. Marc Grawell's answer resolves my issue, no need for further comments

Comment: Func<int, bool> is a function *on a specific instance*, whereas MemberInfo is not tied to an instance. Do you have the instance available in your code?

Comment: What target would you want to call it on? And do you know it's *always* going to return a `bool` and take an `int`? Basically look at `Delegate.CreateDelegate`...

Comment: You might want to check on your premise; "to use it through lambda expression later" - getting a delegate won't help you with a lambda expression

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Func<int,bool> f = (Func<int,bool>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
           typeof(Func<int,bool>), target, (MethodInfo)mi);
```

or on more recent frameworks:

```
var f = mi.CreateDelegate<Func<int,bool>>(target);
```

Note here that `target` is the *object* you want to use, since `func` is a non-`static` method. If it was a `static` method, you can omit that (or pass `null`). Alternatively, you can omit `target` (or pass `null`) if you make it a `Func<Foo, int, bool>` where `Foo` is the type that declares `func`.

However!!! Note that having a `Func<int,bool>` is largely meaningless in terms of creating a lambda expression; lambda expressions *rarely use delegates*.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if there any difference between the `Delegate.CreateDelegate` that you use and the `MethodInfo.CreateDelegate` that I put in my answer?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by your last statement, _"However…lambda expressions rarely use delegates."_?

Comment: @hvd before .NET 4.5, a very big difference: `MethodInfo.CreateDelegate` doesn't exist

Comment: @stakx I'm interpreting the context here as relating to `Expression` types - expression trees. Those use `MethodInfo`, not delegates.

Comment: Hah, that's a good difference. :) In that case, I'll just vote for your answer and remove mine.

Comment: Note, on C#9 (and poss/prolly before) this produces a no-explicit-conversion error.  So, either (cast) the result or use var.

Comment: @stardotstar also there's a more useful helper method from .net 5 onwards (see edit)